# Phrase similar to damages done

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a phrase for when one assigns a money value for damages done by a natural disaster or by an identity thief?

This is more like the value assigned to damages than an actual money transaction.

This is all I can think of: damage done, virtual loss.

Comment: Economic impact, financial losses, etc. + Assessment, valuation, analysis, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's plainly an assessment of the damages. Have a look at [this](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/avengers-damage-manhattan-would-cost-160-billion-322486) humorous take on the damages the Avengers defense of New York in the first movie would have done.

The sum stems from a disaster-cost prediction and **assessment** firm. On their [website](http://www.kinanco.com/detailed-asset-damage-information-real-time-hazards) they use almost exclusively the verb assessment.

Comment: Yes.  "Damages were assessed at ..."  (Estimates are preliminary.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like "appraisal" is the word you're wanting. It literally means "the act or process of assessing something or someone" and is commonly used in colloquial English conversation, especially when evaluating the value of something for insurance purposes.

See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appraisal

When discussing damages, usually the word "estimate" is used. This is because it's not possible to evaluate damage done until repairs have been completed, since you can't calculate the total cost of work without actually doing it.

See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estimate

Comment: +1 for estimated. I was going to answer in same vein The total damage from Katrina **is estimated** at $108 billion 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Katrina